# Button with text below icon

Tags: qt

I am very new to QT UI development.

I need to create a button with text below the icon. There is no option to set this property to the QPushButton.

When I tried to search in the net, they told me to use QToolButton. When I used the QToolButton I could set the Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon. But I couldn’t find a way to change the dimension i.e.  Width, height, x and y position.

How can I display an icon with text below the icon in Qt? Any suggestions?.

Comment: Hi I got a way to set the x, y, width and height property to the QToolButton.
QToolButton btn;
btn ->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 50, 50));
one more thing I want to know is that, I can’t set flat button property.
Because there is no function like that in this class. 
My requirement is to have a button with flat style. When clicked on the button it should be in selection mode. 
Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For **QToolButton**: all that you need (i.e. width, height, x, y) QToolButton has! Take a look [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtoolbutton-members.html) and here some methods:

```
setFixedHeight ( int )
setFixedSize ( const QSize & )
setFixedSize ( int, int )
setFixedWidth ( int )
```

What about QPushButton, probably it does not support changing placement of icon and text. But maybe some how it's possible, for example reimplementing paintEvent() methods or doing update() with setStyleSheet() methods. (But this is not the noob way, sorry)

By the way [here](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/) is some interesting "changed" Qt widgets...

Good luck.